# Identifying subfields by some form, from a migration of being referenced by _id in another collection

Tags: mongodb

The tructure used to be:

```
City collection with documents like: {_id, name, buildings:[ _ids from Building collection ]}
Building collection with documents like: {_id, name}
```

and turned to:

```
City collection with documents like: {_id, name, buildings:[ {_id, name}, {_id, name}...]}
```

Now my problem is thus: the _id in the building jsons in the "buildings" sufield used to be generated by mongodb, and I just inserted it into the "buildings" array to the respective city document.

But now, when I create a building, i insert it directly in the array. But I still require clientside some sort of an identification to each individual building, but I am puzzled how exactly to do that.

I was thinking of holding a numeric value in the city document which I increment each time I insert a building, and give it that id. This way, it will be unique to that particular city. Thus, all cities with one default building will have that building with id 0.

Is there a smarter / more elegant solution to this?

P.S: I would also like **easy** access to each individual building, do you also think I should hold them as an associative array / object with the key being the id?

Comment: Which mongodb client are you using? i.e. what programming language are you accessing the database with?

Comment: nodejs, latest version

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of holding a numeric value in the city document which I increment each time I insert a building, and give it that id.

That's not a very good idea, as that means that for every update, you also need a read for this. What is best to assign an _id value in the same mechanism that MongoDB would have done - by creating an ObjectID value. Actually, it is the *driver* that generates those IDs, and not MongoDB itself.

The documentation at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html shows how to do that:

```
var objectId = new ObjectID();
```

And then just add this value next to name in your building sub-documents.